# Terraform resource allocation

Tags: terraform

If I create infrastructure with terraform and after that, someone removes some resource manually from AWS and recreates same manually. What if I do terraform apply. Will it recreate the code?

Comment: This entirely depends on the resource in question. Do you have a more concrete question?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it depends on the resource being managed.

Most AWS products have IDs that are generated automatically. Hence, you can't really recreate a resource you've destroyed. Even if the configuration, name and tags are equal, the new resource will have a different ID. That's the case of EC2 instances, for example.

There are exceptions to this rule, S3 buckets being one. The ID of a S3 bucket is its own name. The ARN (another identifier used by AWS) is also derived from its name. Hence, if you delete a bucket and recreate it, Terraform will just keep managing the newly created bucket.

In general, if you need Terraform to use resources that will be managed manually, you should use [Data Sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html). This way Terraform can look for stuff using other parameters besides resource IDs.